# Creating a panel that stays on top of applications

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome

When using the [Spotify web app](https://open.spotify.com) I can open a mini-player panel (using button [1]). The mini-player [2] stays on top every window, even when switching browser tabs or applications. Note that I'm using Chromium on Chromium OS.

[image]

Can this be done using html/js or is this a Chrome or even Chrome OS only thing?

Comment: switching tabs within the spotify app (simple css) or actual chrome tabs? If the latter, I'm curious as well

Comment: Actual chrome tabs and between applications. It stays on top of e.g. my terminal window.

Comment: I can confirm that it works on windows in the same behaviour.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is done using the Picture-in-Picture API which is currently only supported in Chrome. Here's an example from Google using the PiP API: https://googlechrome.github.io/samples/picture-in-picture/

Comment: Thanks! Here is a link to the W3C draft document: https://w3c.github.io/picture-in-picture